# CloudFile.Exists()/ExistsAsync() throws 403 (Unauthorized) if directory in the path doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

Let's say I get a reference to a possibly non-existent file, like

```
var file = rootDirectory.GetFileReference("fakepath1/fakepath2/fakefile.jpg");
```

I find that if either of the directories `fakepath1` or `fakepath2` don't exist, then

```
file.Exists()
```

or

```
await file.ExistsAsync()
```

both result in 403 rather than returning false.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Per my local validation, I can get result **False** when the directory doesn't really exist. The key question is: What's your credentials used to call this API? For example, is it a **Shared Access Signature** that doesn't have read access to the file share?